# Get Python3 to show the correct tzname

Tags: python, encoding

I'm trying to see the timezone name. So here is the code in Python2:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:24) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import time
>>> time.tzname
('\xd6\xd0\xb9\xfa\xb1\xea\xd7\xbc\xca\xb1\xbc\xe4', '\xd6\xd0\xb9\xfa\xcf\xc4\xc1\xee\xca\xb1')
>>> a = time.tzname[0]
>>> print(a)
中国标准时间   # correct output
```

So far so good. My computer is Windows7 with default encoding `gbk`.

Then I tried Python3:

```
>>> time.tzname
('ÖÐ¹ú±ê×¼Ê±¼ä', 'ÖÐ¹úÏÄÁîÊ±')
>>> a = time.tzname[0]
>>> print(a)
ÖÐ¹ú±ê×¼Ê±¼ä
```

So what actually happened here when using Python3? How to get the correct output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't mean to answer this question at first, but after I wrote the whole question, I found the answer, so I write it down.

The reason for this is that it's not using the correct encoding, where `gbk` should be used but Python chose `latin-1`. This proves it:

```
>>> print(a.encode('latin-1').decode('gbk'))
中国标准时间
```